# making css animation class reload once it is already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so the question here is how can i get the class "fadeInUpBig" to reload when a different button is clicked to the first one.

So if you click any of the buttons the class is added and works fine.

But if i then want to click another button and have the class in effect reload it doesn't and just presents the different color associated with the other button with n o"fadeInUpBig"

a few people have tried to help with this but no joy.  Please help !

I have provided a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/uvb4qp2m/11/

the html of this is ...

```
<h2 class="iconM-testimonials text-center">What is </h2>
<h2 class="iconM-referrals text-center">What is Music </h2>


    <div id="colorscreen" class="animated"> </div>
```

pretty straight forward !

the css is pretty straight forward and is here...

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; 
    animation-delay: 1s;
}


#colorscreen{ 
  position: fixed;
  top: -20px;
  left : -50px ;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  z-index: -1500;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow : hidden ;

   }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 1000px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUpBig {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpBig;
  animation-name: fadeInUpBig;

}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Light_', 'Open Sans Light', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0.00em;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;


}
```

and lastly the javascript for the two buttons is here...

```
$('.iconM-testimonials').on('click', function () {
     $("#colorscreen").removeClass("fadeInUpBig").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
      $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(164, 196, 0, 0.2)');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");


});


$('.iconM-referrals').on('click', function () {
     $("#colorscreen").removeClass("fadeInUpBig").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
      $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(183, 192, 26, 0.8)');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");


});
```

the core of the problem seems to lie within the removeclass and add class lines of the script as it doesn't seem to do anything and on the second button click it just changes the color associated with that button.  #pullingmyhairout

Comment: Have a look a this demo. It removes (#colorscreen) and appends its to the body -- http://jsfiddle.net/zuy5es7c/

Comment: It's because the browser doesn't see any changes to the DOM after the method call which removes then adds the same class. So it doesn't make any updates. One way to fix this is add the class in a setInterval call with a very short counter.

Comment: Hi Yes the jfiddle worked well thank you so much ! , It would be great if they happened continuously so there was no white space between the transitions but i guess that is another question

Comment: i noticed that you remove the div colorscreen , in which case maybe i should take it out altogether ?

Comment: ... and reading your response chRyNaN i now understand thankyou.... Tasos' answer was great because it negated the need to use a setinterval timer which is also great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in a comment, the reason why the animation isn't restarting is because the browser doesn't see any change in the classes of the element from before to after the method call. So, it doesn't actually remove then add the class; it just leaves it on. One way to trick the browser into applying the update you want is by adding the class in a setTimout call:

```
$('.iconM-testimonials').on('click', function () {
    $("#colorscreen").removeClass("fadeInUpBig");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
        $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(164, 196, 0, 0.2)');
    }, 1);
    $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
});
```

Comment: @r3wt Yes, even on `animationend` you would need to add the class back to the element in a timeout. Really on any method or event call you where you attempt to remove and then add the same class.

Comment: no, you just remove it inside of the closure for animationend. that's how i do it. animationend doesn't fire until the duration of the animation ends. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, though. there is certainly many ways to skin a cat, especially in javascript.

Comment: @R3wt That's odd that you've accomplished this in animationend. I've personally had to do the `setTimeout` way in animationend before. Because even once the animation ends the class isn't removed. Perhaps, it's browser specific as I haven't tested it largely cross browser.

Comment: thanks for the answers yes the above answer seems to work... if only i could get the animations to occur with no white space while transitions occur ... another question perhaps .

Comment: i appreciate the responses here from both of you... I think a timer is not going to be suitable as the next part of my question will be how can these transitions happen without any intermitent white space while the fadeinupbig effect/class works ..... i think that one is going to be really tricky even taking out the animation delay still leaves a space so there has to be some sort of additional javascript to copy the color set by the previous button until the fadeinupbig effect moves in/up to the whole of the page.

Comment: @user3504751 i'll update my answer for you. what you are doing is non trivial. like not even hard at all. you just don't have the experience and familiarity yet with javascript/jquery. trust me, what you want is easy. you're going about this entirely in the wrong way though.

Comment: I am sure that I am , care to elaborate friend ?

Comment: @user3504751 elaborating will teach you nothing. you must live it my friend! may the force be with you.

Comment: ironically i think that teaches me nothing , ...bloody starwars ! :p

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
$('.iconM-testimonials').on('click', function () {
    $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(164, 196, 0, 0.2)').promise().done(function(){
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
        $('#colorscreen').addClass('fadeInUpBig').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){
            $('#colorscreen').removeClass('fadeInUpBig');
        });
    });
});


$('.iconM-referrals').on('click', function () {
    $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(183, 192, 26, 0.8)').promise().done(function(){
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
        $('#colorscreen').addClass('fadeInUpBig').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){
            $('#colorscreen').removeClass('fadeInUpBig');
        });
    });
});
```